# How to use the select query to find the value inside a stringifed JSON

Tags: json, sqlite

I want to check whether a particular id is available in a column which is storing the data in stringified JSON.how could i use the select statement for it.I have used update statement with replace function to change the value in the json.But how to find whether an id exists or not in the json.

```
[{"name":"Ramesh","mobile_no":"6420000000","location":"Erode","type":"Worker","contact_id":2237,"farmer_id":84,"date":"2018-01-19T05:55:31.283Z","category":"Working","transaction_type":"WorkerWork","amount_in":80,"user_type":"Worker","id":11532}]
```

Comment: Which value do you want to filter from the above string

Comment: @ragu i would like to filter the contact_id from the above column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE instr(column_name, '"contact_id":2237') > 0;
```

If you want that total count only

```
SELECT count(*) as alias_name FROM table_name WHERE instr(Column_name, '"contact_id":2237') > 0;
```

Keep in mind instr is case-sensitive

Comment: let me try this one